# How can I replace a class that's already loaded?

Tags: php, class, overriding

I have a system that uses an auto loader to load a class. I am able to edit the auto loader, but I want people to be able to extend one of my classes and have my system still run.

Lets say class A is the original and class B is the new one that extends class A.

I have:

```
A.php
namespace Core;
class A{}

B.php
namespace Core;
class B extends OverriddenA{} ( Explained below )
```

When the autoloader loads A - instead of actually loading A, I want it to load B, which requires the real A to be loaded. So it should look like this:

```
include 'A.php';
class_alias('A', 'OverriddenA');
include 'B.php';
class_alias('B', 'A');
```

The problem is that the second `class_alias()` errors because A is already loaded as A.

Presently the only solution I can think of is to do a file_read_contents(), replace the class name and run an eval() - but I would really hate to do that.

Comment: One thing I can think of is if I can somehow load A inside a different namespace. So while the file declares it as as Core\A, can I have the class loader load it as Overridden\Core\A, then have class Core\B extend Overridden\Core\A ?

Comment: Why do you need that? You'd assign a variable. `$a = new A(); include('B.php'); $b = new B();`

Comment: Well, it's impossible anyway. An alias is only a reference, not a new name.

Comment: There's a lot more to it - there is basically a whole mass of code that will be looking for class A and I need it to see class B instead. Using aliasing I can load B as A, but I can't have it extend A without copying all the code which is also messy.

Comment: Why are you not assigning a variable, use the variable and if you need to extend the class, you can overwrite it with the new class B.

Comment: That's the proper way, I've never seen a code where isn't a variable used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a great way to do this.

The class that the system will look for is `Core\A`

So that file is actually created as `Overridable\A`

When it's loaded, the class loader sees that it's overridable so it looks if it's overridden. If it is, it loads the override which already declares itself as `Core\A extends Overridable\A`

If there is no override, but it's in the Overridable namespace, it creates an alias: `class_alias(Overridable\A, Core\A);`

And just so my IDE can still be able to reference everything, I create a file called Overrides.php which is never actually included that just says:

```
namespace: Core;
class A overrides \Overridable\A {}
```